# Reverse for 'admin' not found. 'admin' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and ,I'm trying to run a piece of code but keep getting this error: Reverse for 'admin' not found. 'admin' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

The urls.py is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include("ttgen.urls")),
path('account/', include("account.urls")),
```

]

The login.html is as follows:

```
<div class="login-form">
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
  <p><input type="submit" value="LOGIN"></p>
</form>
<p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot your password?</a></p>
```

The views.py is as follows:

```
            if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse('Authenticated '\
                                    'successfully')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
else:
    form = LoginForm()
return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

The traceback error

```
Environment:


    Request Method: POST
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/

    Django Version: 4.0.6
    Python Version: 3.10.4
   Installed Applications:
   ['account',
   'ttgen',
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles']
   Installed Middleware:
   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
    **callback_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 92, in 
   sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in 
   _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 67, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 119, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 153, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 99, in form_valid
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 70, in get_success_url
    return self.get_redirect_url() or self.get_default_redirect_url()
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 86, in 
   get_default_redirect_url
    return resolve_url(self.next_page or settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 145, in resolve_url
    return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lin Laptop\PycharmProjects\Testing\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 802, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /account/login/
    Exception Value: Reverse for 'admin' not found. 'admin' is not a 
    valid view function or pattern name.
```

This error appears every time I try to login.

Comment: by default, the admin URLs are behind the `admin` namespace, for example `{% url 'admin:login' %}`

Comment: Please share with us the full traceback error

Comment: Are you using an admin login page or your own custom login page? The reason for this error is this "action='{% url 'login' %}'" piece of code. Let me know which login page are you using and then we can solve this.

Comment: It's a custom login page.

Comment: @JonathanQuispe please set this as the answer so that I can upvote.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the admin URLs are behind the `admin` namespace, for example `{% url 'admin:login' %}` unless you have a custom login page, in which case you need to use the name of your custom login page.